# Retornar JSON salvo em localStorage

Tags: javascript, json, localstorage

Estou tentando recuperar um JSON que eu salvei em localStorage, na função `salvarOffline()`. Com o código como está a função `listarHorarios()` eu recebo um `undefined` e o laço de repetição não funciona. Meu código:

```
function salvarOffline(data) {
    window.localStorage.setItem("horariosOffline", JSON.stringify(data));
}

function listarHorarios() {
    listaFormatada = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('horariosOffline'));
    var tabelaHorarios = document.querySelector('.horarios');
    for(var i = 0; i < listaFormatada.horarios.length; i++) {
        var linhaHorario = document.createElement('tr');
        linhaHorario.innerHTML = 
        '<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">' + listaFormatada[i].linha + '</td>' +
        '<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">' + listaFormatada[i].partida + '</td>' +
        '<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><strong>' + listaFormatada[i].chegada + '</strong></td>';

        tabelaHorarios.appendChild(linhaHorario);
    }
}
```

A estrutura do meu JSON é:

```
{
    "horarios": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "linha": "Avenida",
            "horario": {
                "partida": "7:20",
                "chegada": "7:40"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "linha": "St. Antônio | Avenida | S. Sebastião",
            "horario": {
                "partida": "7:25",
                "chegada": "8:00"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: O problema é que você está chamando `listaFormatada[i]` quando era pra ser `listaFormatada.horarios[i]` ... veja funcionando em [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-h6oyre?file=index.js)

Comment: Realmente funcionou, obrigado @wmsouza !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A array em questão é `horarios` e não `listaFormatada`, portanto o correto seria chamar `listaFormatada.horarios[i]`.

Outra coisa é que o JSON possui objeto aninhado, logo os valores de `partida` e `chegada` estão em um segundo nível do objeto, teria que acrescentar a chave `horario` onde estão esses valores.

Um exemplo de como ficaria seu código:

```js
var json = {
    "horarios": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "linha": "Avenida",
            "horario": {
                "partida": "7:20",
                "chegada": "7:40"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "linha": "St. Antônio | Avenida | S. Sebastião",
            "horario": {
                "partida": "7:25",
                "chegada": "8:00"
            }
        }
    ]
}

function salvarOffline(data) {
    window.localStorage.setItem("horariosOffline", JSON.stringify(data));
}

function listarHorarios() {
   json = JSON.stringify(json);
    listaFormatada = JSON.parse(json);
    var tabelaHorarios = document.querySelector('.horarios');
    for(var i = 0; i < listaFormatada.horarios.length; i++) {
        var linhaHorario = document.createElement('tr');
        linhaHorario.innerHTML = 
        '<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">' + listaFormatada.horarios[i].linha + '</td>' +
        '<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">' + listaFormatada.horarios[i].horario.partida + '</td>' +
        '<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><strong>' + listaFormatada.horarios[i].horario.chegada + '</strong></td>';

        tabelaHorarios.appendChild(linhaHorario);
    }
}

listarHorarios();
```

```html
<table class="horarios"></table>
```

Seu código original corrigido:

```
function listarHorarios() {
    listaFormatada = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('horariosOffline'));
    var tabelaHorarios = document.querySelector('.horarios');
    for(var i = 0; i < listaFormatada.horarios.length; i++) {
        var linhaHorario = document.createElement('tr');
        linhaHorario.innerHTML = 
        '<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">' + listaFormatada.horarios[i].linha + '</td>' +
        '<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">' + listaFormatada.horarios[i].horario.partida + '</td>' +
        '<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><strong>' + listaFormatada.horarios[i].horario.chegada + '</strong></td>';

        tabelaHorarios.appendChild(linhaHorario);
    }
}
```